# Android - SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder - Set background color

Tags: android, sqlite

I retrieve from database my swimming performance. I would like to change background color of one field according to his value. For example if i swimm 4 laps I want color background. I try this code that set background correctly but text disappears.

```
        String[] columns = new String[] { "swimm_pos", "swimm_date","swimm_lap", "swimm_stroke", "swimm_time", "swimm_media", "swimm_efficiency", "swimm_note" };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.row_counter, R.id.swimm_date, R.id.swimm_lap, R.id.swimm_stroke, R.id.swimm_time, R.id.swimm_medialap, R.id.swimm_efficiency, R.id.swimm_note};

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, 
            R.layout.contacto_list_item, 
            cursor, 
            columns, 
            to);

        adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
              if (view.getId() == R.id.swimm_lap)
                { 
                  int color = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
                  String s = String.valueOf(color);
                  if (s.equals("4")) {
                  TextView tv = (TextView)view;
                  tv.setBackgroundColor(0xFF558866);}
                 return true;

            }
              return false;}

        });
```

And is also possible, when lap is equals to 4 set background color of another field, for example in my code: R.id.swimm_pos?
thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning  true from ViewBinder implies that you are also binding the data to the View.

But in your case you are not setting the text of R.id.swimm_lap.

So add setText before return statement

```
tv.setText(s);
return true;
```

Edit:
For the second question suppose you want to change background of R.id.row_counter depending upon swim lap then add

```
else if (view.getId() == R.id.row_counter){ 
 int color = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("swimm_lap")); 
 if (s.equals("4")) {
     view.setBackgroundColor(0xFF558866);
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Perfect. and for the second question is possible to add something like: TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.modificacontatto.edswimm_pos);

Comment: I edited the answer, I guess if you are just changing color, you could return false instead of setting the text, but if it does not work, you will need to set the text too

Answer (score 0):

Solved, here the right code:

```
         adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
              if (view.getId() == R.id.row_counter)
                { 
                  int color = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("swimm_lap"));
                  String s = String.valueOf(color);
                  if (s.equals("4")) {
                  TextView tv = (TextView)view;
                  tv.setBackgroundColor(0xFF558866);
                              }
                 return true;
            }
              return false;}
        });
    this.setListAdapter(adapter);
    datasource.close();
}
```